# Custom box environment with custom border

Tags: border, box

I try to make a kind of custom datatype which has a short ID a description and an owner comment. Using `minipage` with no border is not optimal because it is difficult to see the separation between items.

Using the full border is not too much beautiful in my opinion. Thus, would it be possible to use a left border only and get a better separation?

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve it (I do not necessarily look for `minipage`, any solution would be OK).

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}\[t\]\[1\totalheight\]\[b\]{1\columnwidth}%
\begin{description}
\item \[{ID}\] 0445ax
\item \[{Description}\] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Etiam purus urna, placerat non lectus at, blandit venenatis
nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus
malesuada, libero et faucibus varius, nibh lectus fringilla sapien,
in tempor dui metus vitae mauris. 
\item \[{Owner\,Coment}\] Sed cursus consequat enim, eget elementum erat
volutpat in. Nam efficitur felis eget urna cursus vestibulum. Duis
non felis fringilla, tempor massa ut, sagittis nibh. Vivamus nec erat
eget risus tincidunt tristique id eu ex. Suspendisse potenti.
\end{description}
%
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know which packages you are loading. If you don't want to load additional packages, use `\fbox`, otherwise there are many nice packages like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`.

Comment: I load no specific package only fontenc inputenc and babel on the example I gave. But I do not mind using packages. I will have a look at the package you mention. Any recommendation between the two?

Comment: I am not an expert and all I am going to say has to be taken with a grain of salt. According to what I know, `tcolorbox` might be a bit more powerful but `mdframed` might do better with page breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeset the description environment with more indentation. I'm using the KOMA-script addmargin env for this purpose. If you have another documentclass, probably you have to load the scrextend package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext, lipsum}

\newcommand{\customdata}[3]{
  \textbf{ID}\hspace{2em} #1
  \begin{addmargin}[1cm]{0pt}
    \begin{description}
    \item[Description] #2
    \item[Owner Comment] #3
    \end{description}
  \end{addmargin}
  \bigskip
  }

\begin{document}

\customdata{0445ax}{\blindtext}{\blindtext}

\customdata{03425ax}{\blindtext}{\blindtext}


\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

I don't understand what OP means with border, but maybe this helps further:

```
\documentclass{article}%{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\newcommand{\lipusm}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Etiam purus urna, placerat non lectus at, blandit venenatis
nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus
malesuada, libero et faucibus varius, nibh lectus fringilla sapien,
in tempor dui metus vitae mauris.
}

\newcommand{\customdata}[3]{%
  \rule{1ex}{4ex}~\textbf{ID}\hspace{2em} #1

  \begin{addmargin}[1.2cm]{0pt}
    \begin{description}
    \item[Description] #2
    \item[Owner Comment] #3
    \end{description}
  \end{addmargin}
  \bigskip
  }

\begin{document}

\customdata{0445ax}{\lipusm}{\lipusm}

\customdata{03425ax}{\lipusm}{\lipusm}


\end{document}
```

[image: picture of picture]

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. However, I do not see how you solve the 'border' problem. (By 'border' I meant having a left frame [such as a black line] on the left side)

I do know how to get an empty boder/frame , I do know how to get a full border/frame , but I do NOT know how to get a border/frame only on the left side...

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution with `tcolorbox`. It uses an already defined enviornment `mydesc` to be adapted with `tcolorbox` borders. It controls breaks between pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{mydesc}{%
\begin{description}}{\end{description}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{mydesc}{% 
    enhanced, breakable,
    blanker,
    before skip=6pt,
    after skip=6pt,
    left=4mm,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}}

\newcommand{\mydata}[3]{
\begin{mydesc}
\item[ID] #1
\item[Description] #2
\item[Owner Comment] #3
\end{mydesc}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\mydata{0445ax}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[3]}

\mydata{0445ax}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[3]}

\mydata{0445ax}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[3]}

\mydata{0445ax}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

[image]